# JavaScript (ES6) code snippets doesn't work with Vs Code version 1.75

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently, I updated my VS code, and JavaScript (ES6) code snippets stopped working. The current version of VS Code is 1.75.

I have uninstalled the extension and installed it again, but nothing works.

Comment: I assume you mean you aren't seeing the snippets in the suggestions popup.  If you type the entire prefix do they show up?

Comment: no. they didn't show up.

Comment: Possibly this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173244. Try the insiders version, or update us when you get v1.75.1 on whether the issue still reproduces.